# Remove name from macOS Sierra menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

In previous versions of OS X, you could remove the name from the menu bar. I can no longer find the option for this in the Users & Groups window in System Preferences.

[image]

Searching Google and even this site hasn't provided any answers, so how do you do it?

Comment: My name, by default, does not appear on the menu bar in macOS (10.12.3) however I only have one account. Does your system have more then one account (other then Guest) setup?

Comment: I did a google search and, literally, the first 8 items returned indicate how to do this on Sierra.

Comment: @fsb good for you, I did a few searches and could not find the answer. Hence I asked here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> click on Home icon (Login Options) -> Show Fast User Switching as **icon**

[image]
[image]